# FIND_IN_SET in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `extra_info` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `category` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `event` 
    (`id`, `name`, `extra_info`, `category`, `date`, `is_deleted`) VALUES
    ('1', 'EVENT1', 'dog', 'other','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0'),
    ('2', 'EVENT2', 'cat', 'sport','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0'),
    ('3', 'EVENT3', 'fruit', 'sport','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0'),
    ('4', 'EVENT4', 'coffee', 'sport','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0'),
    ('5', 'EVENT5', '', 'sport','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0'),
    ('6', 'EVENT6', '', 'sport','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0'),
    ('7', 'EVENT7', '', 'other','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0'),
    ('8', 'EVENT8', '', 'sport','2020-08-21 12:25:48', '0');


CREATE TABLE `event_has_keyword` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `event_has_keyword` 
    (`event_id`, `keyword_id`) 
VALUES
    ('3', '4'),
    ('6','2'),
    ('8', '1'),
    ('6','6'),
    ('8', '2'),
    ('6','3'),
    ('1','4'),
    ('3', '3');
    

CREATE TABLE `event_keywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO `event_keywords` 
    (`id`, `name`, `is_deleted`) 
VALUES
    ('1', 'labrador', '0'),
    ('2', 'dog', '0'),
    ('3', 'cat with space', '0'),
    ('4', 'keyword1', '0'),
    ('5', 'keyword2', '0'),
    ('6', 'keyword3', '0');
```

What I am trying to do is to find all events where CATEGORY, EXTRA_INFO or KEYWORD matches to given query.

```
SELECT E.*, K.`name` AS keywords, GROUP_CONCAT(K.`name`) AS keywords
       FROM `event` E 
       LEFT JOIN `event_has_keyword` EK 
            ON E.`id` = EK.`event_id`     
       LEFT JOIN event_keywords K
            ON EK.`keyword_id` = K.`id`
       WHERE E.`is_deleted` = 0 
            AND FIND_IN_SET (K.`name` , 'labrador,dog,cat,cat with space,other') 
            OR FIND_IN_SET (E.`category` , 'labrador,dog,cat,cat with space,other') 
            OR FIND_IN_SET (E.`extra_info` , 'labrador,dog,cat,cat with space,other')
       GROUP BY E.`id`
       ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

I need to combine FIND_IN_SET to work on all columns `K.'name'`, `E.'category'` and `E.'extra_info'` not only one. 
So when I am looking for 'labrador,dog,cat with space,other' I should find all events where:
`K.'name'` is **labrador** or **dog** or **cat** or **cat with space** or **other** and 
all events where `E.'category'` is **labrador** or **dog** or **cat** or **cat with space** or **other** and
all events where `E.'extra_info'` is **labrador** or **dog** or **cat** or **cat with space** or **other**

In following case I should receive:

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| id | name   | extra_info | category | date                | is_deleted | keywords                      |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 1  | EVENT1 | dog        | other    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          | keyword1                      |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2  | EVENT2 | cat        | sport    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          |                               |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 3  | EVENT3 | fruit      | sport    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          | keyword1, cat with space      |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 6  | EVENT6 |            | sport    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          | dog, keyword3, cat with space |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 7  | EVENT7 |            | other    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          |                               |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 8  | EVENT8 |            | sport    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          | labrador, dog                 |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

but I still receiving only:

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| id | name   | extra_info | category | date                | is_deleted | keywords                      |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 3  | EVENT3 | fruit      | sport    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          | keyword1, cat with space      |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 6  | EVENT6 |            | sport    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          | dog, keyword3, cat with space |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 8  | EVENT8 |            | sport    | 2020-08-21 12:25:48 | 0          | labrador, dog                 |
+----+--------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

so it is searching only through keywords `K.'name'` and ignoring `E.'category'` and `E.'extra_info'`

when trying to add brackets:

```
WHERE E.`is_deleted` = 0 
    AND (FIND_IN_SET (K.`name` , 'labrador,dog,cat,cat with space,other') 
    OR FIND_IN_SET (E.`category` , 'labrador,cat,dog,cat with space,other') 
    OR FIND_IN_SET (E.`extra_info` , 'labrador,cat,dog,cat with space,other'))
```

it returns null

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any error or result mismatch ? please add expected result

Comment: thanks! question edited

Comment: Use IN rather than find_in_set

Comment: I can't get the results from your current query with this sample data. Can you create a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 with your sample data and the results that your current query returns?

Comment: Two problems: Insert statement for `event` has `;` in between statement so some records are not inserted and second why do you expect event id 2 in the result set ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 thanks! it was mistake made during creating this question. Corrected. Mea Culpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` and `cat with space` are not the same string. You have to add `cat` separately to find into the set. Here the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e1b7f/15) works according to your desire.

```
SELECT E.*, K.`name` AS keywords, GROUP_CONCAT(K.`name`) AS keywords
   FROM `event` E 
   LEFT JOIN `event_has_keyword` EK 
        ON E.`id` = EK.`event_id`     
   LEFT JOIN event_keywords K
        ON EK.`keyword_id` = K.`id`
   WHERE E.`is_deleted` = 0 
        AND (FIND_IN_SET (K.`name` , 'labrador,dog,cat with space,other') 
        OR FIND_IN_SET (E.`category` , 'labrador,dog,cat with space,other') 
        OR FIND_IN_SET (E.`extra_info` , 'labrador,dog,cat,cat with space,other'))
   GROUP BY E.`id`
   ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! `cat` and `cat with space` was my mistake made during creating this question. In your  sqlfiddle  it looks completely fine, but (what is strange) on my side it is searching only through K.'name' and ignoring E.'category' and E.'extra_info'. I just noticed that if I leave only `AND FIND_IN_SET (E.`extra_info`,: key_words)` it returns nothing ...

Comment: shuffle the order of FIND_IN_SET and try again. does the problem occurs every time??

Comment: Thanks!  I just noticed that if I leave only `AND FIND_IN_SET (E.extra_info,: key_words)` it returns nothing ...

Comment: Welcome. That's why I said `cat` and `cat with space` are separate

Comment: I checked into sqlfiddle . It's not empty

Comment: It was totally strange... I have shuffle the order once more (as you said) and now it is working correctly. Thanks.